# How to interpret these data about median survival and overall 5-year survival rate

Tags: survival

In a work about a follow-up of lung cancer patients, it is stated that the median survival is -let's say- 12 months. It means that 12 months after the diagnosis there is a survival of 50% of the patients, following the definition of this parameter.

However, in the same work the overall 5-year survival rate is said to be around 80% for these patients. It would mean that 5 years after the diagnosis, there is a survival of 80% of the patients.

So what is wrong here? Are these proportions necessarily mistaken, or can be explained?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a reference and if possible a web link to the publication in question. Sometimes there is presentation of outcomes for different subsets of patients, or for different types of outcomes (e.g., tumor recurrence versus death). You could, for example, have 12-month median time to tumor recurrence and still have 80% 5-year overall survival in terms of death. There is no way to have 80% 5-year survival and 12-month median survival for the same set of patients and the same outcome.

Comment: It is a draft I am reviewing, that lies a bit far away from my expertise concerning in particular these data.  In fact there are reported two sets of patients, one with 12-month median survival and 80% of 5-year survival, and the other 14-month median survival and 90% of 5-year survival. Probably these data are miscalculated or misrepresented, as I deduce from EdM's comment.

Comment: I wonder if they mean 80% or 90% death rather than survival at 5 years? Needs to be clarified.